# Extract/Match specific words from a paragraph in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, typescript, react-native

I'm currently working on a react native (JS based) project in which I need to match and extract Hospitals' names from dynamic paragraphs coming from the backend server. I know about match(), includes() etc but these are not working in this case as names are dynamic and may containing multiple words.

Any suggestions!

Comment: You need to post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I can only get the keyword Hospital using includes() but I need full name of hospital

Comment: You could use split. If the new array only has one element, there were no matches. If it's greater, then you know the number of matches for your word. If you need to know the position of each, they start at the length of each string.

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight the words upon rendering the HTML text.

A regular expression can be created from a list of words via:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${words.map(word => `(${word})`).join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');
```

The raw HTML can be set using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop of the `<p>`.

```js
const highlightWords = ['beef', 'ham', 'pork', 'sausage', 'ribeye', 'ribs'];

class WordHighlighter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { regex: this._updateRegex(this.props.highlightWords), paragraphs: [] };
  };
  
  /* @private */ _updateRegex(words) {
    return new RegExp(`\\b(${words.map(word => `(${word})`).join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');
  }
  
  /* @private */ _highlightWords(paragraph) {
    return paragraph.replace(this.state.regex, `<span class="highlight">$1</span>`);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(paragraphs => this.setState({ paragraphs }));
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const
      curr = JSON.stringify(this.props.highlightWords),
      prev = JSON.stringify(prevProps.highlightWords);
    if (curr !== prev) {
      this.setState({ regex: this._updateRegex(this.props.highlightWords) });
    }
  }
  
  render() {  
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.paragraphs.map(paragraph => (
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this._highlightWords(paragraph) }} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<WordHighlighter highlightWords={highlightWords} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.highlight { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here is a component implementation of the class above:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const words = ['beef', 'ham', 'pork', 'sausage', 'ribeye', 'ribs'];

const updateRegex = (words) =>
  new RegExp(`\\b(${words.map(word => `(${word})`).join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');

const wordHighlighter = (paragraph, regex) =>
  paragraph.replace(regex, `<span class="highlight">$1</span>`);

const WordHighlighter = (props) => {
  const { highlightWords } = props;
  const [ regex, setRegex ] = useState(updateRegex(highlightWords));
  const [ paragraphs, setParagraphs ] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setParagraphs(json)), []);
  
  useEffect(() => setRegex(updateRegex(highlightWords)), [highlightWords]);
   
  return (
    <div>
      {paragraphs.map(paragraph => (
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: wordHighlighter(paragraph, regex) }} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<WordHighlighter highlightWords={words} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.highlight { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I said before.

```js
const par =  "The quick brown fox jumped quickly over the lazy dog.";

const words = [
  "quick",
  "fox",
  "over",
];

function matches(par, words){
  const output = [];
  words.forEach(word => {
    const test = par.split(word);
    if(test.length > 0){
      for(let i = 1; i < test.length; i++){
        output.push(word);
      }
    }
  })
  return output;
}

const ans = matches(par, words);
console.log(ans);
```